# php-fpm cannot acess unix socket

Tags: php-fpm, socket, groups

I'm using different PHP-FPM pools with specific users each one. I just switched memcached to use a socket instead of tcp/udp ports (for many reasons including the recent attacks on the 11211 port).

I’ve modified the systemd unit file accordingly:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/memcached -s /var/run/memcached/memcached.socket -a 0770 -o modern
```

The socket is created with correct permissions:

```
$ ls -la /var/run/memcached/memcached.socket
srwxrwx--- 1 memcached memcached 0 Jul  5 15:41 /var/run/memcached/memcached.socket
```

Then I’ve included the php-fpm pool user into the memcached group so php can connect to the socket:

```
$ gpasswd pooluser memcached
```

Made sure it is:

```
$ groups pooluser
pooluser memcached
```

And finally I’ve configured the php script:

```
$memcached->addServer('/var/run/memcached/memcached.socket', 0)
```

The only reason I can think of is that PHP-FPM is using another user to establish the connection. The php extension fails to access the socket:

```
var_dump($memcached->addServer('/var/run/memcached/memcached.socket', 0))
// bool(true)

var_dump($memcached->set('key', 'value')
// bool(false)
```

If I change the umask to `0777` then it can connect, so it is not a configuration problem, it is a permissions problem.

I'm using another unix socket, to connect `PDO()` to mariadb (mysql), and I've checked and the `mysql.socket` has `0777` by default (at least I didn't configure anything for mariadb).

So should I give unix sockets `0777` permissions or not? In any case I'd like to figure out why php-memcached can't access the socket.

Comment: Did you restart php-fpm?

Comment: The php-fpm pool runs as a user added to group `memcached`. It's the group permission OP is talking about. Is the fpm pool restarted after adding the user to this group?

Comment: Yes, I just restarted it and is still returning false.

Comment: Wait, it is working now, for some reason it was still printing `bool(false)`.